# Set/control the name of an image generated with LaTeX

Tags: pdf

**TL;DR**: I want to control the name of the image resource generated with `\includegraphics`.

I need to have control over the image resource name generated by LaTeX so that I can replace them later.

The purpose for this strange workflow is for a signature process on an existing app:

- The application has the possibility to generate a report
- One module of this report is to display a signature list of persons
- The report with the signature list gets created with latex when the user want's to persist the report as PDF.
- [**NEW**] Now the user can decide that the signature list should be filled with real signatures (a user can decide to start the signature workflow also days AFTER the document got created)
- A signature workflow starts and all signatures are collected as images.
- The report should now be filled with the signatures collected (I cannot newly generate the document after the signatures are all collected because the report's data could already be changed (maybe the signature collection is completed days after the report got created). So my only way is to transform the existing PDF document in some way)

*If you have an idea on how to solve this workflow you are very welcome!*

My idea is to generate the PDF document with the signature list already provided but with image placeholders for the signature image that gets inserted for the placeholders.
I have a working solution that can replace images but the problem is that I have no control over the names of the images with `\includegraphics`. The generated images are named Im1, Im2, ...
I want to give the images special marker names so I can later refer to the names and replace the image with the corresponding signature.

Any idea on how to solve my problem?

Comment: you are using pdftex? I don't think there is any control over the PDF markup generated by `\pdfxform` or `\pdfximage`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle For `\pdfxform` it is possible to determine the resource name <-> object number relationship : `\the\pdfxformname\pdflastxform` <--> `\the\pdflastxform`. Unfortunately, the same doesn't exist for images.

Comment: @AlexG yes but finding out the name isn't quite the same as choosing your own name, which is what I thought the OP wanted. But let's see if OP is happy with your answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As an intermediate step, OP could `sed 's/\/Im/\/whatever/g'` on the PDF. :-) Followed by repairing the `xref` table, of course.

Comment: Finding out the generated name would work if I am able to define a (hidden) mapping between the generated image name and the signature information (coming from a DB).
But this requires that the image replacement process (done with iText7) can find the generated name which I am struggling ATM.

Answer (score 2):

In PDFTeX, image resources are sequentially numbered as they are included. The associated PDF object number of the XObject can be retrieved with `\pdflastximage`. You could record this relationship by writing it into a textfile during typesetting and then let it be used by your external programme to replace the XObject content stream with the desired one (the signature image).

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a} (\texttt{Im1}\ $\Leftrightarrow$\ object No. \texttt{\the\pdflastximage})

\immediate\pdfobj{}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b} (\texttt{Im2}\ $\Leftrightarrow$\ object No. \texttt{\the\pdflastximage})

\noindent\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-c} (\texttt{Im3}\ $\Leftrightarrow$\ object No. \texttt{\the\pdflastximage})

\end{document}
```

Extended version with patched `\includegraphics` to keep track of image resource number (taking into account duplicated images), and writing image resource <-> pdf object number relationship in a textfile. **Note:** This relationship may be broken by the utility used for PDF post-processing.

```latex
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0

\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%patch \includegraphics (maintaining an image counter)
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{ImgCnt}
\pretocmd{\Gread@@pdftex}{
  \edef\Gin@attr@hash{%
    \ifx\Gin@pagebox\@empty
    \else
      :\Gin@pagebox
    \fi
    \ifx\Gin@page\@empty
    \else
      :P\Gin@page
    \fi
    \ifx\Gin@decode\@empty\else
      :D[\Gin@decode]%
    \fi
    \ifGin@interpolate
      :I%
    \fi
  }%
  \@ifundefined{#1 image\Gin@attr@hash}{\stepcounter{ImgCnt}}{}%
}{}{}

%textfile for imageresource<->object number relationship
\newwrite\signObjects
\immediate\openout\signObjects=signobject.txt

\begin{document}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image} % random image

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% the images you are interested in (e. g. placeholders for signatures)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\noindent\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a} (\texttt{Im\theImgCnt}\ $\Leftrightarrow$\ object No. \texttt{\the\pdflastximage})
\immediate\write\signObjects{Im\theImgCnt:\the\pdflastximage\space 0 R}

\immediate\pdfobj{} %create random PDF obj

\noindent\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b} (\texttt{Im\theImgCnt}\ $\Leftrightarrow$\ object No. \texttt{\the\pdflastximage})
\immediate\write\signObjects{Im\theImgCnt:\the\pdflastximage\space 0 R}

%%%%%% random image duplicated
\noindent\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}
%%%%%%

\noindent\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-c} (\texttt{Im\theImgCnt}\ $\Leftrightarrow$\ object No. \texttt{\the\pdflastximage})
\immediate\write\signObjects{Im\theImgCnt:\the\pdflastximage\space 0 R}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting! But I cannot rely on the sequential numbering, because in the report there can be all kind of images before and after the signature block.     

`\the\pdflastximage` looks interesting, but can I access this object id in the generated PDF?     

My idea now is that i add a `\pdfcomment` with a mapping, e.g. {\the\pdflastximage=my-id-i-know}, read all comments, find the mapping, and then find the object id in the PDF to replace the signature.     

But I wasn't able to find this object id in the final generated PDF.

Comment: The first problem could be solved by patching `\includegraphics` so that it maintains a counter for image inclusions. The second problem is due to PDF compression. To produce uncompressed PDF, you can put `\pdfcompresslevel=0\pdfobjcompresslevel=0` at the top of the input file, or uncompress the PDF with a third-party tool before your postprocessing. Also note that whenever you make changes/replacements in a PDF, you need to repair its `xref` table afterwards. This table is a record of the byte-offsets of all PDF objects in the PDF. Otherwise you get a broken, invalid PDF file.

Comment: I'm using iText 7 ([the dotnet version](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet)) for the image replacement part.
`\pdfcompresslevel=0\pdfobjcompresslevel=0` doesn't seem to change anything (maybe iText7 does the uncompression on the fly together with the `xref` reparation).

Comment: I think the best solution is to patch `\includegraphics`, but I don't know how that is done.
Maybe it is possible to patch it so it is possible to provide a 'label' or 'name' that get's used for the resource identifier?
Any guidance/resources on how to patch commands?

Comment: See extended example.

Comment: The counter works! At least partly... If the same image gets rendered two times the Image counter increases, but the internal image count doesn't (e.g. try inserting the middle image two times). The placeholder for the signature gets inserted for each signature. I can work around on that by defining a bunch of placeholder image files but I am not in control of other report images that could possibly be duplicated. If this is the case the whole counting is out of sync.

Comment: Another problem is that it doesn't use Im1, ... always. I am not sure whats causing the behavior, but if I am using other parts of the report the image resource name suddenly becomes R17, R19, ...

Comment: Out-of-sync can be avoided with checking for image duplication based on md5sum. Let me try. May take a second. And place-holder images need to be unique.

Comment: Perhaps iText substitutes resource names. There cannot be done much about this on the TeX side, I am afraid.

Comment: The R17, ... resource names already appear when I read in the PDF information, so I don't think it is a iText specific behavior? Noob question: does a (non developer ) tool exist that I can use to inspect a PDF document?

Comment: `pdftk` for uncompressing. But it mixes up object numbers in the output :(

Comment: Using the md5 sum sounds interesting! This could be the solution!
If it is possible to calculate the md5 of the image (as uncompressed bitmap?) then it should be possible to cross relate the md5 with the signature information...

Comment: But then every placeholder has to be a bit different, but I can work with that. ;)

Comment: Ok, duplicated images are detected now. Using code that `graphics` pkg uses for hashing.